# Div flashing when removing class with visibility

Tags: javascript, css

I'm having an issue with a notification system I am building.

All works fine till the end where my javascript is triggered to remove the show class from the notification div. When the class is removed, there is a brief flash to the start position of the div.

[Example here](https://gyazo.com/caecf62f6a6867c4385265f64424ff6e)

JS to show notification:

```
function showNotification() {
   notificationRef.current.classList.add("nShow");

   setTimeout(() => {
     notificationRef.current.classList.remove("nShow");
   }, 4000);
}
```

Notification CSS has general positioning and styling with `visibility: hidden` and `top: 85px` set.

nShow (class to show notification):

```
.notification.nShow {
   visibility: visible;
   animation: fadeNotiIn 1s, fadeNotiOut 1s 3s;
 }
 @keyframes fadeNotiIn {
   from {
     top: 0;
     opacity: 0;
   }
   to {
     top: 85px;
     opacity: 1;
   }
 }

 @keyframes fadeNotiOut {
   from {
     top: 85px;
     opacity: 1;
    }
   to {
     top: 0;
     opacity: 0;
   }
 }
```

It seems that visibility: hidden is being set after opacity: 1 so there is a flash when removing the show class.

Thanks

Comment: hello @Tom can you add a working example with youre code so we can test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample. I would not advise you to use `animation` here. Between the two animations you plan, your element goes back to its default state and that's making things ugly.

Instead, what I would do is use a short `transition` to smooth a bit the thing between the two states, and keep handling it through JS.

```js
const notification = document.querySelector('.notification');
function startNotification() {

  notification.classList.add("nShow");

  setTimeout(() => {
     notification.classList.remove("nShow");
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
.notification {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.notification.nShow {
     top: 85px;
     opacity: 1;
 }
 
 .root {
  position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="startNotification()">Start notification</button>
<div class="root">
  <div class="notification">Hello</div>
</div>
```

As said in the first version, I don't think you should go for `visibility` and `opacity` at the same time, and since you are already using opacity, let's use it completely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I tried this previously, however due to .notification having opacity 0 and the slight pause in between both animations, it sets opacity 0 mid animation [as seen here](https://gyazo.com/16c4287b3538cbfc225331ca083a453f)

Comment: Working on a sample :) BRB

Comment: Here it is, I think you should use `transition` instead, because as you noticed, if you plan multiple animations, the graphic configuration of your element is resetted between both parts of your animation.

Comment: Good idea, feels a little "hacky" since technically the element is present on the page. You can fix this by adding `pointer-events: none` to the .notification class and `pointer-events: all` to the .nShow class means that any buttons/text can only be highlighted when then notification is visible. Will wait a bit to see other responses, but will accept if there are no other solutions. Thanks!